# Uploaded to S3 with HAML files

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, haml, middleman

I am super web development noob, and I HAML instead of regular HTML files. I went through the steps to upload to S3, and everything worked fine with the test index.html file, but when I uploaded my HAML files, nothing worked. I created the files with Middleman, if it matters.  I know this is a stupid question but I looked around for a long time and didn't find anything.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to process `haml` files to generate the html, but s3 is for static content only (static html pages), so I don't quite follow what you are doing over here.

Comment: We have no idea what your code looks like, so all we can do is guess about what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Seens like him is using a blog system like jekyll or others, well, since you write the pages with haml, i guess you have a option to process these files and generate the static html files.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
set :haml, :format => :html5
```

to your config.rb. You may find this [site](http://tropism.me/blog/2012/10/13/static-site-development-with-middleman-and-foundation/) helpful

Comment: That option only sets the HTML 5 option for HAML. It doesn't cause the files to be built. Rafael Oliveria is correct, the files needs to be built with `middleman build`.